# Checking if the file exists in the path and set the Button depending the result

Tags: ios

I want to check whether if the file exists and set the Button depending the result, but I am getting nil value from the function **getAudiofileName** every time . which is the better way to design this function . How can i do this in a good way . I am struggling in this section as days. Can anyone point me what's going wrong.

```
        NSString *audioFile = [self getAudiofileName:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"audiofile=%@",audioFile); // Getting nil everty time

    if (!audioFile) {
        [SoundsCell.customBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [playBtn setEnabled:NO];
    } else {
        [SoundsCell.customBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"listen.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [playBtn setEnabled:YES];
    }



    [SoundsCell.customBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(getconnection:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    SoundsCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    [delegate.delArrAlbumDetailCell addObject:SoundsCell];
    return SoundsCell;

}



- (NSString *)getAudiofileName:(int)IndexRow{


    NSLog(@"delegate.SoundsArr %d",[delegate.SoundsArr count]);
    selectedClip = [delegate.SoundsArr objectAtIndex:IndexRow];

    NSString *toendstring;
    NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp3", selectedClip.clip_name];

    NSLog(@"temp =  %@", temp );
    NSLog(@"temp =  %@", selectedClip.clip_url );


    if (temp != nil) 
    {
        toendstring = temp;
        NSLog(@"toendString =%@", toendstring);

    }

    NSString *audioFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",self.dataPath,toendstring];
    NSLog(@"playing audioFilePath =%@", audioFilePath);
    NSFileManager *filmanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if([filmanager fileExistsAtPath:audioFilePath])
    {
        return toendstring;
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }


}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

General critique:

- Use an `IBOutlet` rather than iterating over nib top level objects - it's simpler.
- learn to distinguish between class names and instance names and constants (that goes for Apple programmers, too).
- as the previous poster says, don't return a string for "NotExist"; return `nil`
- temp in `getAudioFileName:` will never have zero length (although it could be `nil`)
- Java style accessory names reveal too much about a programmer
- when initialising a cell, you can put all the stuff that won't change on reuse in the `if (cell == nil)` block; or better, do it in the nib.

Now the answer.  Cells can be any state when they are reused, so you will need to set download as well as play, e.g.:

```
   if (!audioFile) {
       [SoundsCell.customBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DOWNLOAD.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [playBtn setEnabled:NO];
    } else {
       [SoundsCell.customBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PLAY.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [playBtn setEnabled:YES];
    }
```

And you may well need to change the action.

Comment: Wow, 20 years doing Cocoa; seriously impressive. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `getAudiofileName()` function has a poorly-designed API: it is a bad idea to return `"NotExist"` if it can't find a file name to return. If the sound file is named `"NotExist"`, this routine cannot give a reasonable answer.

Instead, you should pass the filename back to the caller as a *parameter* and success / failure in the return value. Or, return `nil` to indicate failure.

Comment: here i am passing the filename back as a parameter .. right ? otherwise how i can i do

Comment: Parameters are passed to the method/function, return values are, uh, returned.  You could pass by reference rather than value, which is what sarnold is implying.  However, I wouldn't consider that appropriate in your situation; just return nil for not found.